# 16.04 - Network Menu gone and clicking Connect does nothing

Tags: networking, wireless

I don't know how long it's been gone. I just switched my home wireless network today and that's when I noticed. The network menu is gone. So I go to `System Settings > Network > Click the '>' next to my networks name.` There is a `Connect` button and a `Settings` button. Neither of them do anything at all.

I open from the command line and see the following error:

[image]

AFAIK I haven't made any major changes to this computer recently. Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Have you tried "Forget Network" and then re-creating the connection?  I usually use "Network Connections" to manage my connections.  It seems to give you more options, and I usually set up static IP's on my machines through "Network Connections"

Comment: Does this happen in the guest session too?

Comment: You could look at what `nmcli` shows you (see http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/nmcli.1.html)

Comment: @SunnyDaze  Forget Network and re-create crashed. http://i.imgur.com/x0Q5y0A.png

Comment: @Fabby Guest sessions gives the same thing. Actually guest sessions was buggy and I had to manually hit the power button to bring up the shutdown/restart dialog.

Comment: @guntbert http://i.imgur.com/1kiXts0.png

Comment: @dolphonebubleine please don't post screen shots of terminal output, that is much harder to read. You can [edit] your question and format the code by indenting every line with 4 spaces.

Comment: @guntbert do you any idea what the problem is or not? Your opinion about internet manners is not what I asked for.

Comment: @dolphonebubleine it's not about manners but about readability.

Comment: Hate to butt into your discussion but I found it hard to read too until I double clicked on the image and chrome zoomed it in for me. The GUI portion had to be done with a screen capture anyway so I think having the text included in the same image isn't a real violation of the "rules". Some would suggest a separate copy and paste for the text but ... *shrugs*

Answer (score 3):

Although I personally never had this problem, I did a little digging and the closest I could find is [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2239214).

### Here is the gist of the solution

The smarter way to save the security key, along with other settings is to do it via Network Manager settings (nm-applet menu > `Edit Connections` > `Wireless` tab > double-click your connection > `Security` tab). That is the frontend to handle those key files.

Assuming something might have broken in Network Manager installation while upgrading, you may try to completely purge it, then re-install it. To download the packages in advance (since you'll lost internet connection as soon as you purge it) -

```
sudo apt-get install -d --reinstall network-manager network-manager-gnome
```

Then to purge it -

```
sudo apt-get purge network-manager-gnome network-manager
```

To reinstall it (I suggest a reboot in-between) from the downloaded packages, simply -

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome
```

Comment: Thank you for the steps but it still isn't working. I am going to reinstall the OS.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry it didn't help. Perhaps reinstalling the OS is best considering it crashed when you selected "Forget Network". Something else to mention is Iv'e had problems with IPv6 turned on and had to resort to IPv4 only in the connection settings. Something to keep in mind in the future.

Comment: It's all good. It only takes a few minutes and all the junk I've accumulated is gone. I'm back!

Comment: Yes I can see the value of getting rid of accumulated junk. I've done many an `sudo apt-get install` to only use an application once and loose interest. Welcome back and hope the network problem doesn't happen again.

Answer (score 2):

I got same error few days back here is my solution

step 1: - Restart Network services

```
sudo service NetworkManager restart
sudo service network-manager restart
sudo reboot
```

After this Network menu will appeared back again

Comment: Tried it but it still isn't there. Thanks for the suggestion. I'm just going to reinstall.